# Transform orgin not being implemented

Tags: javascript, jquery

Attempting to transform an images scale (zoom) BUT maintain it inside it's parents left and top div so only trying to transform it down and to the right. Setting the transform orgin does not seem to work, what am I missing?

the following code zooms the image on each button click, but pushes the left and top out of the parent div.

```html
 $('element').click(function{
   $('#element').css({'transform':'scale(' + scale + ')' });
   $('#element').css({'transform-orgin':'top left'});
})

<div style "max-wdith:1080px; height: 700px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll">
   <img id="element" src=" src="https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2017/03/castle_moat-100714623-large.jpg" " class="img-flud">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
var x = 400 + 'px';
var y = 300 + 'px';

$('#element').css({
    'transform-origin':         x + ' ' + y + ' 0px',
    '-webkit-transform-origin': x + ' ' + y + ' 0px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer!

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

function zoomIn(e) {
  const scale = 0.1;
  const img = document.querySelector('#my-image');
  $('#my-image').css({transformOrigin: "top left", transform: 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
}

btn.addEventListener('click', zoomIn);
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

div > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="my-image" src="https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2017/03/castle_moat-100714623-large.jpg" />
</div>
<button>Zoom In</button>
```

Comment: How would I set the `transform-orgin` in jquery like you have it? I have tried the above syntax in jquery like you are setting in you css but it does not work

Comment: I tried `$('#element').css({'transform-orgin':'left top'});` the image still scrolls right off the page with each button click

Comment: Hi @KyleLaster, I think you're not getting the expected result because "transform-origin" works together with the css "transform" property. Updated the answer using the correct properties.

Comment: I currently already have transform set and on each button click it does zoom, but still not keeping the top left and top in place. it still transforms and pushes left and top out of parent div.

Comment: This is weird, please, check the jQuery version you're using, try to use a modern version.

Comment: going to update code so you can see full code gimme a sec

Comment: Hey Pablo, I updated full code to see if it helps and version of jquery is new so I think v3.5.1

Comment: the button works you can zoom in on each click as intended, but the top of the image and the left of the image keep zooming right off the page.

Comment: Can you please update your code snippet as I did? This way I can investigate what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, yes of course. Just updated the logic

Comment: Hey Pablo! Any update on this by chance? It seems everyone else has no input haha

Comment: Hi @KyleLaster, please, write a fiddle on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/) and send me the link, so I can edit it for you.

Comment: Hi @KyleLaster, I updated my answer accordingly to your needs. How this helps you.